# Arnoldi iteration and minimal poly

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I'm working on Exercise 33.3 on Numerical Linear Algebra by Lloyd Trefethen. The problem is: if Arnoldi iteration runs to completion on matrix $A$, and $A$ is a $m$ by $m$ square matrix, then the minimal polynominal of $A$ is of degree $m$.

My thoughts are: If Arnoldi runs to completion, then $A$ has full rank, i.e., eigenspace of $A$ has degree $m$, therefore all eigenvalue of $A$ are distinct, hence minimal polynominal is the characteristics polynominal, so their degree are both m.

I'm not sure if the logic follow through, I'm not very familiar with minimal polynominal and characteristics polynominal. So can someone help me check on that please?

Thanks

Comment: It is not necessary for $A$ to have full rank to have Arnoldi iteration run to completion. It is also not necessary for the eigenvalues of $A$ to be distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I note in my comment, your approach is incorrect.

The key is to note that Arnoldi iteration runs to completion with the initial vector $b$ if and only if the Krylov subspace generated by $b$ is equal to all of $\Bbb R^m$.

From there, one approach is to show that the matrix of $A$ relative to the basis $\{b,Ab,\dots,A^{m-1}b\}$ is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix); the fact about the characteristic polynomial follows. Alternatively, the fact that the vectors $b,Ab,\dots,A^{m-1}b$ are linearly independent implies that the *matrices* $I,A,\dots, A^{m-1}$ are linearly independent, and we can similarly deduce from this that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So Krylov subspace generated by b is equal to all of Rm basically means <b, Ab, ... ,A^{n-1}b> spans Rm right?

Comment: I'm condused about the alternative way: so linearly independent matrices implies minimal polynominal of A has degre m?

Comment: @PetaGlz To your first comment: yes, that's exactly what that means. To your second: also yes; the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$ is equal to the smallest $k$ such that the matrices $I,A,A^2\dots,A^{k-1}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much!